# GAE: port_sqlite fails on local dev server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

On my OS X local dev server, when I try to port an existing datastore to sqllite using port_sqlite (in combination wit use_sqlite), I get this error:

> google.appengine.runtime.apiproxy_errors.ApplicationError:
>   ApplicationError: 3 Data in
>   /Users//Documents/workspace-data/datastore/.datastore is corrupt or a
>   different version. Try running with the --clear_datastore flag.
>
> DatabaseError('file is encrypted or is not a database',)

The datastore works fine in the regular non-sqlite way.

What do I do? Thanks.

Comment: I had the same migation problem. I used the --clear option.

Comment: I'm hoping to migrate without doing --clear_datastore and losing all my data.

Comment: I forgot this one> Add this to your env_variables:   TMP: C:\Users\eigenaar\AppData\Local\Temp     # special for sqlite stub

Comment: I tried on my Mac, and it doesn't help. (I do see where you are coming from on this issue: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7717)

Comment: I forgot I added this to my app.yaml. Even with the datastore cleared I could not use sqlite. This fixed my problem, after clearing the datastore. I use Windows, Eclipse and Pydev.

Comment: Yes, I added to app.yaml. And again, I'm trying to do port_sqlite, not clear_datastore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was on the old dev server. It works properly now on the new dev server.

Answer (score 0):

The clear datastore works in some cases.
I found that removing the --logs_path argument or replacing it with a new file also may help
--logs_path=/pathtologs/newfile.log
The devserver writes to the log file with logging.info(). The log entries are stored in a sqllite3 database. It is getting corrupted.